# How to I pass a formula to an excel file in vba

Tags: excel, vba, formula

All I want to do is put a function into a specific cell in excel from vba.  I have tried ws.Range("A2").Value and .Formula.  I can write a text string to that location, but as soon as I define mString with an equals sign in it, both give me an application error.  I'm sure it's something simple, I'm just stuck.

```
Sub Update_CCP()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim mString As String

Set ws = Sheets("Consolidated Client & Prospects")

mString = "=IF('4 Prospects'!A"

ws.Range("A2").Formula = mString
```

Comment: You need a working formula - you can’t assign a partial or broken one

Answer (score 1):

an example of a formula being used in VBA,

```
Sub InsertFormula() 
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B3").Formula = "=RAND()" 
End Sub
```

So in worksheet 1 in the Range A1:B3 to use the =RAND() formula. Have a read of the `.formula` method